# Can we share an .eslintignore file between repos

Tags: eslint

I currently have a shared eslint config that's kept in the npm module `@my-scope/eslint-config`. This is working well, but I was hoping that including the `.eslintignore` file in that npm module would also be shared but it doesn't look like it is shared. What's the best way to share this `.eslintignore` file between projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you explicitly added the .eslintignore file to the files array of your package.json?

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files

Have you tried specifying an --ignore-path pointing to your other .eslintignore? As described here:

http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#using-an-alternate-file

Comment: I confirmed the `.eslintignore` file is in the published npm package.

Comment: Have you tried specifying an --ignore-path pointing to your other .eslintignore? As described here: http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#using-an-alternate-file

Comment: That works, but it's a little less than ideal since I have to manually point the `--ignore-path` to the node_modules folder.

Comment: True. It would be nice if there was a way to tie it together with the eslint config

Answer (score 1):

I replaced my `.eslintignore` file with the `ignorePatterns` in the config file. And then I share the config file between repositories.

Definitely cleaner than pointing to node_modules folder.

Documentation: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/ignore#ignorepatterns-in-config-files